# System.OutOfMemoryException on file download

Tags: asp.net, memory-management

I have an ashx handler with the following code. The idea is to hide the path of the file and prompt a download

```
       context.Response.Clear();
       context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
       context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
       context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
       context.Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
```

This works fine for some files however on others i get

**Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.**

Comment: What is the length of the files that throw the exception?

Comment: It's IIS7, the size all the file is 7mb. It's sometimes works. I think i should wrap this in a using statement. Any thoughts on what it should implement

Comment: I answered a workaround, OutOfMemoryException is a generalist error. You should check your Application Pool and it memory limits, your workerprocess (w3wp) memory (> ~800 Mb could cause this problem), your system available memory (> ~85% load could cause this problem).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very weird, 7Mb is really small. Maybe there's a low limit on your Application Pool ?

If you only need a file download handler, use **HttpResponse.TransmitFile()** which don't buffer the file in memory.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: @joe, see in this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx, httpRuntime -> maxRequestLength and probably appRequestQueueLimit   --- did I make wrong ?

Comment: @Aristos, Oh I see ! You mistake **Request** limit and **Response** limit ;) Since the file is transmitted by the server, its a response and not a request. And a Request limit don't throw OutOfMemoryException which mean a real memory problem.

Answer (score -1):

You have filled system memory.  With larger files, transferred data is buffered in memory.  I would suggest creating your own custom caching method.